# What does an Exchange Managed folder mailbox policy do? For shared mailboxes?

Tags: exchange-2007

Sorry if this is too simple a question, but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here. We have Exchange 2007 running on a SBS 08 VM. My predecessor SysAdmin setup about 6 "shared" mailboxes in Exchange. He then granted appropriate permissions to people for the shared mailboxes. Now there are about 10-12 people using them and each person's Outlook profile has to be manually customized to add the extra mailboxes to his/her Outlook. Try as I may, I cannot teach our end users how to set this up, they just cannot remember how to do it. They hop around a lot, and each time someone goes to a different computer, I have to manually setup these extra mailboxes in his/her Outlook profile.

Could a Managed Folder policy fix this so that their profile syncs automatically with the secondary mailbox(es) in sub-folders? If not, what might accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed Folder Policy has nothing to do with the mailboxes displaying in Outlook.

If you upgrade to a later version of Exchange, then a feature called Automapping will connect a mailbox to an Outlook profile automatically when the user has permissions. Alas this was introduced in Exchange 2010. As you are using a product that is close to 10 years old, an upgrade is probably overdue.

Until you upgrade, you are stuck with manually adding the mailbox to Outlook.

Comment: Very good, thank you. Yes, we are upgrading our Exchange this year since it's getting EOL'd by Microsoft. Business owners squeeze every cent out of software they can, I'm sure you know how it is sometimes.